# Redirect to my app url from an external url

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic5

In my Ionic 5 App i have to implement Social login For this i am doing like below

```
signInWithGoogle(): void {
    window.open("https://xug5l9nwo4.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/dev/api/auth/google", "_self");
}
```

The Flow Is `Login => external link => go back to app`

The Success url is Like This

```
http://localhost:8100/login/success?state=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjU4YTg0ZjNlLThmYWUtNDEyMi05OTA4LTYzYTMxYzFkYjI5NCIsInJvbGUiOiJ1c2VyIiwiZW1haWxJZCI6ImFiaXIxMC53aXNAZ21haWwuY29tIiwicGhvbmVOdW1iZXIiOiI5MTcwMDM5ODkxNTgiLCJpYXQiOjE1OTM1OTcyNzZ9.BIBVEn2SZa-rPfAEatpxeaXpEjxdXuFLZgMl0euoMsI#
```

my question is will it go inside my app?

Comment: Any reason you're doing it in a new window? usually, you redirect them to google, and google redirects back?

Comment: Why don't you use the `InAppBrowser` plugin to access the external link?

Answer (score 0):

In theory, you could pass a return link when opening the window and setup deeplinks. When the browser redirects to that deeplink, it will open the application (https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/deeplinks)

However, there are many other (and better) ways to resolve oAuth. I suggest you look at some packages for this (Microsoft for example provides many packages including Angular, Facebook provides JS SDK for React and common JavaScript). And since Angular is under Google, I would be surprised if they didn't provide it as well.